# T-SQL Sorting based on alternating columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got the following table, and I need to sort the boxes in alternate columns to make less movements when sorting (a real machine will do that), but i'm completely lost of how i can do it.

I have:

```
    Box | Actual_Cell | Best_Cell
     1  |     10408   |   10101
     2  |     10509   |   10102
     3  |     10101   |   10506
     4  |     10102   |   10408
```

I need:

```
           (Where is)   (Where i will put)
    Box | Actual_Cell | Best_Cell
     3  |     10101   |   10506    (Now cell 10101 is free)
     1  |     10408   |   10101    (Now cell 10408 is free)
     4  |     10102   |   10408    (Now cell 10102 is free)
     2  |     10509   |   10102
```

It is, my `Actual_Cell` of the last record must be my `Best_Cell` of the current record.

I'm using MSSQL 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly lost as to what you mean... could you add more examples?

Comment: @Felipe . . . It is not just the data.  What do `Actual_Cell` and `Best_Cell` mean?  What are the rules for ordering the data.  For instance, why isn't 10102 after 10101?  How does Box 3 end up first?  And what does "Now cell XXX mean"?

Comment: Are we guaranteed that all of these chains of proposed swaps don't form a loop?

Comment: It is strange, why this unclear question have several up votes

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I believe (and have based my answer on) that this table represents a set of moves to be performed. Each move is taking something *from* `Actual_Cell` and placing that item in `Best_Cell`. The goal is to arrange these moves in an order such that no move attempts to place an item into a cell that is already occupied. These moves have already been computed and (unusually) cells here are some external concept, not a reference to the intersection of rows and columns.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are absolutely right it is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the output you're looking for. It may be instructive to change `t.*` to just `*` or `c.*` in the final select to see how the `Chains` CTE has built up the set of swaps:

```
declare @t table (Box int,Actual_Cell int,Best_Cell int)
insert into @t(Box,Actual_Cell,Best_Cell) values
(1,10408,10101),
(2,10509,10102),
(3,10101,10506),
(4,10102,10408)

;With Chains as (
    select Box,Best_Cell,Actual_Cell as Chain,0 as Depth
    from @t where Best_Cell not in (select Actual_Cell from @t)
    union all
    select t.Box,c.Best_Cell,t.Actual_Cell,Depth + 1
    from Chains c
        inner join
        @t t
            on
                c.Chain = t.Best_Cell
)
select
    t.*
from
    @t t
        inner join
    Chains c
        on
            t.Box = c.Box
order by
    c.Best_Cell,
    c.Depth
```

Result:

```
Box         Actual_Cell Best_Cell
----------- ----------- -----------
3           10101       10506
1           10408       10101
4           10102       10408
2           10509       10102
```

This assumes that we don't have any loops in the sample data (so, if box 2's Actual Cell was 10506, we wouldn't be able to solve this)

Comment: I am upvoting because I suspect that your interpretation is correct.